$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{x-n} = 0$ has only one root $(0;1)$
Prove that: $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{x-n} = 0$$ has only one real root in $(0;1)$ for all positive integer $n>1$
Here is what I tried:
Rewrite the equation as:
$$\frac{(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n) + x(x-2)\ldots(x-n)+ \ldots + x(x-1)\ldots(x-(n-1))}{x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n)} = 0$$
Put: $$f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n) + x(x-2)\ldots(x-n)+ \ldots + x(x-1)\ldots(x-(n-1))$$
Then:
$$f(0)f(1) = (-1)^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!<0$$
Thus it will have real root in $(0;1)$

By your reasoning you showed that $f$ has at least one real root in $(0,1)$, not "exactly one".

I want to show that it is there is only one real root not at least

You can use the same argument to show that there is one root in (1,2), in (2,3) etc, up till (n-1,n). Since the polynomial f has degree n, it has n roots, and you found them all. So there can only be one in the interval (0,1).

If it has two roots then its derivative will have to vanish at some point (by Rolle's Theorem). But the derivative  is striclty negative at every point of $(0,1)$.

Can you explain more specifically for how to use Rolle's Theorem because I don't know how to prove the striclty negative at every point of (0;1)

Derivative of $\frac 1 {x-k}$ is $-\frac 1 {(x-k)^{2}} <0$.

Using calculus, $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x-\alpha}=-\frac{1}{(x-\alpha)^2}$, so the derivative of the original function is always negative.Therefore, it can have only one real zero in the region $(0,1)$ where it's continuous.
You already showed that it has indeed at least one zero, so it must be unique.

As Zima wrote in comment, you proved there is at least one root.
To prove there is at most one root, note that every term monotonically decreases for $x \in (0, 1)$ - so the sum also monotonically decreases, and assumes every value at most once.
Slightly simpler observation to prove there is at least one root: function is continuous on $(0, 1)$, if $x$ is very close to $0$ then the first term is very large positive, and each of the rest is greater than $-2$ - so sum is very large positive. If $x$ is very close to $1$, then the second term is very large negative, the first is at most $2$, and the rest are negative - so the sum is very large negative.
